# How to use a copied text with the "I" and "A" command in a visual block?

Tags: vim, text, insert, selection

I often insert text before or after a visual block using the "`I`" (insert before visual block) or "`A`" command (insert after visual block).
After typing the text and pushing the `<ESC>` key the text is inserted before or after every line in the block.

But what if I want to insert a piece of **copied** text?
This doesn't work: After pasting the text, the ESC key doesn't work anymore and the copied text is only inserted in 1 line.

How can I insert a copied text on every line before or after a block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the selection and enter insert mode as before with `I` / `A`. Then, instead of typing, paste your register from insert mode with `<C-R>"`. (`"` means the default register; you can use others (e.g. `a`) as well.) Conclude with `<Esc>` as before.

See `:help i_CTRL-R` for more information.